# guest authentication

Tags: authentication

I'm newbie to wordpress.
I have created a wordpress website, and would like guest to authenticate against other application I have (Django based).

One option I though about is pushing a cookie once logged in to the other application, which wordpress will authenticate with.

Other option could be get request from wordpress to my Django application.
Would love to hear suggestions on where to start.